# Full-Screen Exclusive mode error

Tags: java, exception, graphics, jframe, fullscreen

I want to use Full Screen mode, but I keep getting a complicated error when I press "F". I am using eclipse and it does not show any errors and everything is imported. If anyone is good with code, can you tell me what I did wrong?

A snippet of the code:

```
GraphicsEnviroment ge = GraphicsEnviroment.getLocalGraphicsEnviroment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.GetDefaultScreenDevice();
private boolean FullScreen = false;
JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);

// Not shown: The JFrame is set up etc., and a separate class extends KeyAdapter and runs keyPressed

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F){
        if(!FullScreen){
            if(gd.isFullScreenSupported()){
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                                    FullScreen = true;
            }
        } else{
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    }
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.
at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Frame.java:923)
at com.Ward.src.main.Game.keyPressed(Game.java:167)
at com.Ward.src.main.KeyboardInput.keyPressed(KeyboardInput.java:15)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `gd` to `GraphicsEnvironment.getGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice()` before you can use it.

**Update:** Now that the OP has fixed this problem, there is another problem. The problem is changing the `undecorated` property on a window that is already being displayed. If the window is being displayed, the `undecorated` property can't be changed, because the operating system can't change the property while it is displayed. I think this can be fixed by omitting the call to `setUndecorated`, the full screen window doesn't have to be undecorated (I think).

Comment: I replaced GraphicsDevice gd; with GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice(); but I still get the error! Help!

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.dispose(); // Fixes the issue
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible();
```

I know this question is old, however I just dealt with this issue myself, solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
if(gd.isFullScreenSupported()){
```

line 165 ? If so, what is `gd set` to ?

The above exception gives you the class/line number that the error occurred on. That should be enough to give you an idea of what is null.

Comment: I think frame.setUndecorated(true); is now returning an error. Can that return an error?

Answer (score -1):

In your code add "setUndecorated(true)" only.
Example:

```
public launch() {

    setSize(300, 200);
    setUndecorated(true);

}
```